# jQuery on() with dynamic selector

Tags: jquery

Trying to toggle the opening/closing of a horizontal menu with jQuery on().

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dU57h/

```
<ul id="mobile-header-left" class="app-btns">
    <li id="m-menu-btn" class="menu m-menu-btn-closed"><img src="img/m-menu.png" alt="Menu" /></li>
</ul>
```

```
/* Open */
$(".m-menu-btn-closed").click(function() {
    $("#m-menu-btn").removeClass("m-menu-btn-closed");
    $("#m-menu-btn").addClass("m-menu-btn-open");
    $("#m-menu").animate({left:'0'});
});

/* Close */
$("#mobile-header-left").on("click", ".m-menu-btn-open", function() {
    $("#m-menu-btn").removeClass("m-menu-btn-open");
    $("#m-menu-btn").addClass("m-menu-btn-closed");
    $("#m-menu").animate({left:'-75%'});
);
```

The menu opens ok, but i can't get it close. I know its got to do with selecting a dynamically added class but am having trouble getting on() working.

If anyone can help, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should use another `on` statement, since you're adding the class dynamically.

Comment: please add a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `m-menu-btn-closed` class from the element doesn't keep the click event that opens the menu from being activated. It's already bound to the element, so it's not affected by changing the class.

When you try to close the menu, the event handler for opening it will also be activated, and you have two animations fighting against each other.

You can use a delegate for the open event handler also, then it will be deactivated when you remove the class:

```
$("#mobile-header-left").on("click", ".m-menu-btn-closed", function() {
```

Alternatively, you can use a single event handler, and figure out inside it what to do when the button is clicked:

```
$("#m-menu-btn").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(".m-menu-btn-closed")) {
    $(this).removeClass("m-menu-btn-closed").addClass("m-menu-btn-open");
    $("#m-menu").animate({left:'0'});
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("m-menu-btn-open").addClass("m-menu-btn-closed");
    $("#m-menu").animate({left:'-75%'});
  }
});
```

Comment: That seems to be a far more elegant approach, and it works. Thanks Guffa!